# jQuery Flot opacity depending on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, plot, flot

Hope you are well.

I am in need to change flot bar/pie color depending on it's value.

For example I have data as

```
data = [
    { label: "Label 1", color: "orange", data: 10}
    { label: "Label 2", color: "orange", data: 20}
    { label: "Label 3", color: "orange", data: 70}
];

$.plot(placeholder, data, options);
```

Label 3 as largest one should stay orange and Label 2 and Label 1 should have opacity (for example each -10% will give -10 to opacity).

Something like that:

[image]

Any ideas or hints in right direction?

Thank you!

P.S. Label values will change dynamically, so I can't just add predefined colors.

Comment: Just set opacity to the value/100? So the 10% pie would have .1 opacity and the 70% pie would have .7 opacity. You could also make it so the biggest pie is 1 opacity and the others are relative to that so that 10% would have 1/7th opacity and 20% would have 2/7ths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edited, this should work

```
    var data = [{ label: "Label 1", color: "rgba(255,165,0,1.0)", data: 10},
        { label: "Label 2", color: "rgba(255,165,0,1.0)", data: 20},
        { label: "Label 3", color: "rgba(255,165,0,1.0)", data: 70}]

    var maxOpacity = 0;

    data.forEach(function(a) {
        maxOpacity = Math.max(a.data, maxOpacity);
    });

    data.forEach(function(a) {
        var opacity = (((a.data * 100) / maxOpacity) / 100).toFixed(2);

        if (a.color.indexOf('rgba') == 0) {
            var b = a.color.split(',');
            b[3] = opacity;
            a.color = b.join(",") + ")";
        }
    });

    var placeholder = $("#placeholder");

    $.plot(placeholder, data, {
        series: {
            pie: { 
                show: true
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: That is something, thank you. But how I can combine that back and push  to $.plot(placeholder, data, options); as data (or any other array)?

Comment: Any idea how to convert color: "orange" to rgba add opacity value to each and put them together as { label: "Label 1", color: "orange with opacity", data: 10}? :)

Comment: I already started to do some code with getRGBA plugin, but this is looking much shorter! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code snippet can help you. I didn't test it and it may not fit exactly to your code, but I think my main thoughts are visible :) .

```
var array = [{ label: "Label 1", color: "orange", data: 10},
    { label: "Label 2", color: "orange", data: 20},
    { label: "Label 3", color: "orange", data: 70}];

array.sort(function(a, b){
    var a1= a.data, b1= b.data;
    if(a1== b1) return 0;
    return a1 > b1? 1: -1;
});

var arrLength = array.length;
var opacitySteps = 100 / arrLength;

for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
    element = arr[i];
    element.color = opacitySteps * i;
}
```